# What is the best way to create a V1 UUID in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, uuid

AFAIK, `Guid.NewGuid()` generates a V4 UUID. Is there a way I can generate a V1 UUID from the standard libraries that are provided?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the documentation for [System.Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=netcore-2.2)

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid you will need to implement it yourself if you are not happy with [examples](https://github.com/TechplexEngineer/plexview/blob/fe3313132206410782a0193757318ab9a43900ae/OpenMetaverseTypes/UUID.cs) [available](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=UUID%20extension%3Acs%20language%3AC%23&type=Code) on GitHub or generating [online](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version1).

Some related articles explaining the UUID formats

- [Understanding How UUIDs Are Generated](https://digitalbunker.dev/understanding-how-uuids-are-generated/)
- [A Complete Guide to UUID Versions (v1, v4, v5)](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/10/05/uuid1-vs-uuid4/)

Comment: Not a single one of the examples referenced is an actual V1 implementation.

Comment: What do you mean @Steven? V1 just means UUID is generated by using a combination the host computers MAC address and the current date and time.